# Gmaps4rails custom info window with javascript content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails and I need to execute javascript inside a marker's info window. Every marker's underlying object has a sound file associated with it, and I want to be able to play that file inside the info window. The player I'm using is jwplayer and it is instantiated with javascript call with few params.

I've tried to use the gmaps4rails own method to insert the code into info window like below

```
def gmaps4rails_infowindow
  "<div id='jwplayer_#{self.id}'>Here comes the player...</div>
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">
      //<![CDATA[
        jwplayer(\"jwplayer_#{self.id}\").setup(#{options});
      //]]>
   </script>"
end
```

but that doesn't work. Actually anything with a < script> tag inside that method seems to break the gmap4rails map loading anyway I try it.

Is there a way to get javascript executed inside the info window by using gmaps4rails, or do I need to roll some other solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to add any `<script>` in gmaps4rails (as well as raw google maps API I guess).

You should deal with this problem using `click` event on the marker + `close` event of infowindow.

Use the callbacks to add these functions.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me direction. I guess I will try to insert the sound file path into info window in a hidden element and then use callbacks to scrape that and instantiate the player.

Comment: How exactly can I access the 'close' event of the Infobox in Gmaps4rails?

Comment: There is nothing specific to gmaps4rails regarding javascript. Infowindow objects are stored for each marker from Gmaps.map.markers. When you iterate, marker.infowindow will retrieve the object on which you can simply work as in any google map app